# Factory only retrieves $http on load of app, how to force it to retrieve feed every time controller calls it?

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple factory:

```
.factory('NewsHandler', function ($http) {

  return $http.get('http://server.com/feed/news.json');

});
```

And in my partials I'm calling this factory like so:

```
  $scope.news;
  NewsHandler.success(function(data) {
    $scope.news = data;
  });
```

It seems the factory is only called once the app loads. I'm trying to get it to load every time I go from one partial to another and back. How can I make sure that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular services are singletons and cached by the injector after first retrieval. With your code, the value returned by `$http.get('http://server.com/feed/news.json');` is cached and reused throughout the app.

Try something like this:

```
.factory('NewsHandler', function ($http) {
  return {
      get: function() {
         return $http.get('http://server.com/feed/news.json');
      }
   };
});

  $scope.news;
  NewsHandler.get().success(function(data) {
    $scope.news = data;
  });
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for explanation and the code sample :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.factory('NewsHandler', function ($http) {

  return function(){return $http.get('http://server.com/feed/news.json')};

});

$scope.news;
NewsHandler.success(function(data) {
   $scope.news = data();
```

});

asuming data is your service